# How to use ChannelDuplexHandler instead of SimpleChannelInboundHandler

Tags: java, netty

I used to create my business logic handler by SimpleChannelInboundHandler like this

```
@Override
public void channelRead0(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx,final RpcRequest request) throws Exception {
    logger.debug("receive request",request);
    Response response = new RpcResponse(request.getRequestId());
    try {
        Object result = Server.handleRequest(request);
        response.setResult(result);
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        response.setError(throwable);
        logger.error("",throwable);
    }
    ctx.writeAndFlush(response).addListener((ChannelFutureListener)
            channelFuture -> logger.debug("Send Response for Request " + request.getRequestId()));
}
```

Now I want to use ChannelDuplexHandler to separate write from channelRead but I don't know how to do it,it's really hard to find example about ChannelOutBoundHandler

Comment: You could create a `RequestHandler` class which subscribes to your `ChannelDuplexHandler` class and gets notified during the `channelRead0`. The listener then would invoke the `Server.handleRequest` (and do error handling etc.) and will respond the result to the `write` method of your `ChannelDuplexHandler` class

Comment: I am not really sure what the problem is... can you be more specific ?